# FlowPane height change measurements

Tags: dynamic, height, javafx, flowpane

I have a `Stage` as a form with a `FlowPane`. I just add Strings to the `FlowPane`. The main target with the flowpane is to create a "Tag" like control. This Tagcontrol is in the middle of the form.

Without or only one/two items the `FlowPane` should only have the same height as a `TextField`. When adding more and more Strings the `FlowPane` should increase its height till a certain maximum. While increasing the height of the `FlowPane` till its maximum also the height of the `Stage` should grow.

Now: how do I get the needed delta-height of the `FlowPane` when adding more and more items. For example on the first row I have two strings, on the second row i could right 5 strings depending of the string-length. If I have the delta i can use this to increase the height of the `Stage` easily.. but I am stuck with this calculation of flowheight-change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just messed around somewhere else in the code. You can just bind the height of the flowpane and you're good.

Comment: What did you bind the height of the flowpane to?